# Is there a way to access PythonAnywhere CPU Allowance from a script?

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I'm curious how my CPU allowance on PythonAnywhere is trending over several days.  Is there a way to access this value from a script such that I can setup a Schedule task to take readings once an hour and save them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>PythonAnywhere dev here: There isn't, unfortunately, but that's a great suggestion!  I'll add it to our list.</s>

**Update**

And here is new (2019-09-11) API endpoint:

```
/api/v0/user/{username}/cpu/
```

GET Returns information about cpu usage in json format:

```
{
    "daily_cpu_limit_seconds": <int>,
    "next_reset_time": <isoformat>,
    "daily_cpu_total_usage_seconds": <float>
}
```

see [the blog post with example of usage](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/181/).

Comment: Thank you Giles.  At a minimum, maybe a sparkline or something for past day and past hours. Or just provide the hooks and I'll make a script to collect it.

Comment: No, it's not been a very popular request, unfortunately.